# Rails 4 doesn't call my controller's default_url_options method from my HAML view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the host and port for all `link_to` calls from my HAML views. I implemented `default_url_options` in my controller(s), but it is never called.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def default_url_options
    { host: 'mysite.com:34567' }
  end
end
```

Where `ApplicationController` is `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Is this supposed to work? Perhaps someone can point me to a working example?

I am using Rails 4.2.4

Comment: Quite likely the answer is also the correct answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737407/rails-default-url-options-does-not-work-for-path-helpers-rails-bug?noredirect=1#comment70668750_41737407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok--I couldn't get it to work exactly how I wanted, but I did find a reasonable solution:

1. Create a helper for my controller `link_to_asset`. Using `root_url` respects what is returned by `default_url_options` in my controller.

   ```
   module ApplicationHelper
     def link_to_asset(asset)
       "#{root_url}#{asset.path}"
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use in my view, like this

   ```
   %li.link= link_to asset.name, link_to_asset(asset)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that method be within `ApplicationController`?

That way all controllers will inherit and override the default routes host.

Also note from the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#default-url-options):

> In a given request, the method is not actually called for every single generated URL; for performance reasons, the returned hash is cached, there is at most one invocation per request.

You can also modify your environment to apply it from there, modifying `development.rb` for instance and adding:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'mysite.com:34567'
```

Comment: I had an implementation inside my `ApplicationController` too, and it is never called either. Using `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]` also seems to change nothing.

Comment: Did you restarted the application? Also, if you did, try doing a "spring stop" afterwards and then start the application again. Spring sometimes messes things up.

Comment: Ok--looks like it *does* work for `url_for` called from my controller code, but I want to use it in my HAML view. I will update my question.